# CakePHP - How to continue saving if associated model fails validation

Tags: php, cakephp

Let's say I have an array:

```
array(
    'Foo' => array(
        'field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => 'value2'
    ),
    'Bar' => array(
        'field1' => 'value1',
        'field2' => 'value2'
    )
)
```

Where `Foo` and `Bar` have model relationships set up and have their own validation conditions in he model.

How can I make it so if I am doing `$this->Foo->save();` even if `Bar` fails its validation then it will still go ahead and save `Foo` only

Comment: If you don't need to consider the validation the just ignore it. Why need the both?

Comment: I am considering the validation. If `Bar` fails then `Bar` won't save but `Foo` still will

Comment: Then save them with different `save` calls.

Comment: did you uinderstand what  @b0s3 said?

Comment: Check each one in turn via the `$this->Model->validates()` then call the save dependant on if only `Foo` or both validate.

Comment: Using different save calls will be tricky if I am saving more than one `Foo` and `Bar` with `saveAll` as I will need to grab the new `Foo.id`s and add them to the `Bar` array individually

Comment: I have answered my own question below, it's working for me atm

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->Foo->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany' => array('Bar')), true);
```

Comment: Will this still save Bar if it passes validation?

Comment: no you have to check validation errors and then unbind model.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up doing something along these lines:

If initial save fails, check if there are validation errors for `Bar`, if there are, then unset bar and save again with just `Foo` present in `$data`

```
if ($this->Foo->save($data)) {
    //success
} else {
    $errors = $this->Foo->invalidFields();
    if (!empty($errors['Bar'])) {
        unset($data['Bar']);
    }

    //retry save
    if ($this->Foo->save($data) {
        //success
    } else {
        //failure
    }
}
```