# Cake php - Saving HasMany Associations

Tags: cakephp

I created a hasMany association between a Projects & Comments tables.

From this url : /projects/add, the user can create a new project and write several comments.

The request return an array like this :

```
[
    'name' => 'Project name',
    'comments' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'text' => 'This is a comment on this project'
        ],
        (int) 1 => [
            'text' => 'Comment'
        ]
    ]
]
```

In the validator comments, I added a minLength 30 rules.

In the example above, the validator will return an error on the second comment and block recording.

What I want is to save the project and the good comments, and return an error like this : " The project has been saved, But one or more comment was not saved ".

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31811051/6326906) shows one way to do what you're looking for. Try the save and unbind the hasMany relationship if there are validation errors with the associated model.

I think it would be cleaner to just split the save calls though.

```
if (!$this->Project->save($this->request->data['Project'])) {
    throw new Exception($this->Project->getErrors());
}

if (!$this->Project->Comment->save($this->request->data['Comment'])) {
    $message = 'The project has been saved, But one or more comment was not saved';
}
```

Comment: Hi bill , I understand the logic of the answer on the other topic , but I do not understand yours. Can you explain your answer ?

Comment: Yeah no prob. The other answer takes advantage of model associations, attempting to save all associated data in one call. The problem is that you have a messy else statement if the associated validation fails, unbinding the associated data and attempting another save.  Separating the save calls doesn't take advantage of model associations, but it greatly simplifies the logic.  You only attempt to save the table specific data in each call, which means that data will be saved to the `projects` table even if the `comments` validation fails.

Comment: Tank you for this explication. But with this method, can I use the model of comments inside the projects form ?

Comment: Absolutely!  Not sure what version of cake you're on, but one way is to use the [form helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html) and specify the comment model in the comment inputs like `Comment.comment`.  Another way would be to specify the name field in the options.  `'name' => 'data[Comment][comment]'`